# The class foo can be designed, but is not the first class in the file error

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have this

> The class foo can be designed, but is not the first class in the file

error after adding foo class derived from TextBox in my C# file. How can I pass it, it's very annoying.

EDIT:

I want to have multiple classes in my file. I want to have some classes derived from TextBox that accept specific types of input. I'm not using the designer.

EDIT2:

```
class NumericTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code so we can check it out.

Comment: FYI, If you get the error even after placing your class at the top of the file as the only class, it's time to restart visual studio.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must have more than one classes in your file. Move your class up in the file so that it can be the first class in that file

Visual Studio requires class that was responsible for creation of file to be on top or first class of that file

Comment: I created the file as source file. I had some classes and after that added the class foo: TextBox

Comment: It works but I don't want to do that. I just want to disable the stupid designer.

Comment: I just wrote this: protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e) to validate the text... It's a normal TextBox with some validations...

Comment: You can't just disable designer I think you will have to do how designer wants it. Is there any reason why you can't move it on top?

Comment: If I move it up when I click my file the designer appears. It's also very annoying.

Comment: You can view code by right click -> View Code. I guess you will have to accept and submit to what VS requires :)

Comment: I like C++, it has not stupid limitations. I need to do fast some tools and that's why I use C#. I hope I'll finish soon:) Thanks

Answer (score 7):

If you don't need designer altogether this class attribute should do the trick:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("")]
```

Comment: This is the solution which I beieve is what Felics is looking for.  I too have some code, as ServiceBase, which I never ever need to "design".  I used this solution and it fixes things for me.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear.  You have a .cs file containing multiple classes.  Move each class to it's own file and you should be fine.

EDIT: If you insist on having all classes in the same file, then put the `foo` class at the top.  Order matters- by convention, the designer uses the first class in the file for controls.  You cannot have multiple control classes in the same file without seeing this error.

Comment: I don't use designer. I don't want to use designer. Is pure code there. I created the file as Code file.

Comment: If you don't use the designer, then you shouldn't be seeing this error message.  The designer is what shows it.

Answer (score 0):

Either your `class.Designer.cs` file OR your `class.cs` file will have another class defined at the top of it. Since the class is defined in both files as a `partial` class be sure to check both of the files!

Answer (score 0):

ALso,the name of the file must match the name of the class.  For example file myClass.designer.cs expects the class myClass    So check for typos.