# How to solve this Call stack on this program

Tags: c#

Error: the class choosedisplay can be designed, but is not the first class in the file. Visual Studio requires that designers use the first class in the file. 
How to move the class code so that it is in the first class.
I dont Know about program i am a Mechanical Engineer. I trying to do my project in C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using GraphSynth.Representation;
using GraphSynth.Forms;
using GraphSynth.Generation;
    namespace GraphSynth.Forms
    {
        public class chooseViaHumanGui : RecognizeChooseApply
        {
            public override int choose(List<option> options, candidate cand)
            {
                SearchIO.output("There are " + options.Count.ToString() + " recognized locations.", 2);
                if (options.Count == 0)
                {
                    SearchIO.output("Sorry there are no rules recognized.", 0);
                    return int.MinValue;
                }
                else if (options.Count > Program.settings.maxRulesToDisplay)
                {
                    SearchIO.output("Sorry there are too many rules to show.", 0);
                    return int.MinValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    SearchIO.output("Double-click on one to show the location.", 2);
                    chooseDisplay choiceDisplay = new chooseDisplay();
                    choiceDisplay.promptUser(options, (Boolean)(cand.recipe.Count == 0));
                    return choiceDisplay.choice;
                }
            }

            public override double[] choose(option RC, candidate cand)
            { return null; }

            #region Constructors
            public chooseViaHumanGui(Boolean _display)
                : base(Program.seed, Program.rulesets, Program.settings.maxRulesToApply, _display,
                Program.settings.recompileRules, Program.settings.execDir, Program.settings.compiledparamRules) { }
            #endregion
        }

// This is the class Program for choose display //         
public partial class chooseDisplay : Form
        {
            #region Fields
            List<option> rulesToDisplay = new List<option>();
            List<int> optionNumbers = new List<int>();
            public int choice = int.MinValue;
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer checkForStopTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            #endregion


            public chooseDisplay()
            {
                checkForStopTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(processTimer_Tick);
                checkForStopTimer.Interval = 500;
                checkForStopTimer.Start();
            }
            public void promptUser(List<option> RCs, Boolean hideUndo)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                rulesToDisplay = RCs;

                string ruleNo, location;
                int option = 0;

                this.Text = "Choices from RuleSet #" + RCs[0].ruleSetIndex.ToString();

                for (int i = 0; i != rulesToDisplay.Count; i++)
                {
                    option = i + 1;
                    ruleNo = rulesToDisplay[i].ruleNumber.ToString();
                    location = rulesToDisplay[i].location.ToString();
                    recognizedRulesList.Items.Add(option.ToString() + ".\t" + ruleNo + "\t" + location);
                    optionNumbers.Add(i);
                }
                if (hideUndo) this.undoButton.Enabled = false;
                ShowDialog();
            }
                    private void showGraph_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                SearchIO.addAndShowGraphDisplay(rulesToDisplay[recognizedRulesList.SelectedIndex].location.copy(),
                    "Recognized Location " + recognizedRulesList.SelectedItem.ToString());
            }

            private void removeFromList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int numToRemove = recognizedRulesList.CheckedIndices.Count;
                if (numToRemove == recognizedRulesList.Items.Count) 
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You cannot remove all possible options.", "Error",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                else if                 (numToRemove == recognizedRulesList.Items.Count - 1)
                {
                    int[] toRemove = new int[numToRemove];
                    recognizedRulesList.CheckedIndices.CopyTo(toRemove, 0);
                    for (int i = numToRemove; i != 0; i--)
                    {
                        if (toRemove[i - 1] != optionNumbers.Count)
                        {
                            recognizedRulesList.Items.RemoveAt(toRemove[i - 1]);
                            optionNumbers.RemoveAt(toRemove[i - 1]);
                        }
                    }
                    if (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show(
                    "You are removing all but one option [" +
                    recognizedRulesList.Items[0].ToString() +
                    "]. Would you like to apply this option?",
                    "Apply Remaining Option?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question))
                    {
                        choice = optionNumbers[0];
                        this.Close();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    int[] toRemove = new int[numToRemove];
                    recognizedRulesList.CheckedIndices.CopyTo(toRemove, 0);
                    for (int i = numToRemove; i != 0; i--)
                    {
                        if (toRemove[i - 1] != optionNumbers.Count)
                        {
                            recognizedRulesList.Items.RemoveAt(toRemove[i - 1]);
                            optionNumbers.RemoveAt(toRemove[i - 1]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            private void applyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int numChecked = recognizedRulesList.CheckedIndices.Count;
                checkForStopTimer.Stop();

                if (numChecked == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No Options Checked.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    checkForStopTimer.Start();
                }
                else if (numChecked == 1)
                {
                    if (!Program.settings.confirmEachUserChoice ||
                                        (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show(
                                        "Apply Option: " + recognizedRulesList.CheckedItems[0].ToString() + "?",
                                        "Apply Option?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)))
                    {
                        int[] toSaveVector = new int[numChecked];
                        recognizedRulesList.CheckedIndices.CopyTo(toSaveVector, 0);
                        choice = optionNumbers[toSaveVector[0]];
                        this.Close();
                    }
                    else checkForStopTimer.Start();
                }
                else if (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show(
                    "You cannot apply all of these at the same time. Would you simply like to remove all unchecked Options?", "Remove Unchecked?",
                    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question))
                {
                    int[] toSaveVector = new int[numChecked];
                    recognizedRulesList.CheckedIndices.CopyTo(toSaveVector, 0);
                    List<int> toSave = new List<int>(toSaveVector);
                    for (int i = recognizedRulesList.Items.Count; i != 0; i--)
                    {
                        if (!toSave.Contains(i - 1))
                        {
                            recognizedRulesList.Items.RemoveAt(i - 1);
                            optionNumbers.RemoveAt(i - 1);
                        }
                    }
                    checkForStopTimer.Start();
                }
                else checkForStopTimer.Start();
            }
                    void processTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (Program.terminateRequest)
                {
                    recognizedRulesList.SetItemChecked(recognizedRulesList.Items.Count - 1, true);
                    for (int i = 0; i != recognizedRulesList.Items.Count - 1; i++)
                        recognizedRulesList.SetItemChecked(i, false);
                    applyButton_Click(sender, e);
                }

                }

            private void undo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    if ((!Program.settings.confirmEachUserChoice ||
                        (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show("Undo the last rule that was applied?",
                        "Undo Last Rule?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question))))
                    {
                        choice = -1;
                        this.Close();
                    }
            }
                private void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    if ((!Program.settings.confirmEachUserChoice ||
                        (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show("Send Stop message to Generation Process?",
                        "Send Stop?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question))))
                    {
                        choice = int.MinValue;
                        this.Close();
                    }
            }

            }
    }
```

Comment: I know you're having problems. The first thing to try and do is remove as much of the code as possible with only the bare minimum needed to explain your issue. Then explain what it is you are trying to do, what actually happens and what should happen. Remember people what to help you but you have to make easy for them to a) understand & b) you have to show that you've thought about the problem and taken some steps to try and working what you're doing wrong. if you show no effort then the question will have no value and will be closed. in other words show your working!

Comment: Search for error message - http://www.bing.com/search?q=Visual+Studio+requires+that+designers+use+the+first+class+in+the+file and look at top links, prefer MSDN and SO: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43fzdd42%28v=vs.110%29.aspx gives you info on fixing it: "Move the class code so that it is the first class in the file, and then load the designer again."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8864376/3317555. Basically the `choosedisplay` class is sharing a file with another class. All you should have to do is move `choosedisplay` into it's own file.

EDIT: Fixed bad wording.

Comment: I think you mean `into its own file` :)

Answer (score 2):

You've got two classes declared in the same code file.  Move the second one to a different file.

EDIT: Actually, as the second is a form and is probably what that code file was created for in the first place, you should probably move the first class out into its own file.